# How to zoom an entire div?

Tags: jquery, zooming, rotation

I'm fooling around with a function right now on [this page](http://www.kerrydean.ca/Untitled-2.html).

If you click the "who" section the div rotates. I'd like it to zoom and consume the page.

Is this possible? How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After it rotates, set its width and height to be the width and height of the page.

```
$('#who').rotate({
    angle:-90,
    bind: [{
        click: function(){
            $(this).rotateAnimation(0);
        }
    }], // remove the trailing comma here
    callback: function (){
        var $window = $(window);
        $(this).height($window.height()).width($window.width());
    }
});
```

---

#### Edit re: OP's comments

```
$('#who').rotate({
    angle: -90,
    bind: [{
        click: function(){
            $(this).rotateAnimation(0);
        }
    }],
    callback: function (){
        $(this).width(800).height(600);
    }
});
```

See [`.height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height) and [`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width).

---

#### Edit #2

With your current CSS, you need to scale the `img`.

```
$('#who').rotate({
    angle: -90,
    bind: [{
        click: function(){
            $(this).rotateAnimation(0);
        }
    }],
    callback: function (){
        $('#who > img').animate({height: 600, width: 800});
    }
});
```

If you change, say, the image's `height` and `width` to be `100%` then you only need to change the size of the `div` and the image should scale with it.

```
$('#who').animate({height: 600, width: 800});
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that to no avail. I maybe doing it wrong. do i just plug the values in like so?.height($window.height(600))
                .width($window.width(800));   for some reason my original coding is not working in firefox either!

Comment: @Greg: I've edited my answer after looking at how the rotate plugin works. Is that any better?

Comment: Hey Matt, I've got it looking like this $('#who').rotate({
    angle:-90,
    bind: [{
        click: function(){
            $(this).rotateAnimation(0);
        }
    }], // remove the trailing comma here
    callback: function (){
        var $window = $(window);
        $(this).height($window.height(600)).width($window.width(800));
    }
});   does that look how you imagined? It still not doing the zoom. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Greg: did you update it on your site? I don't see the latest version in your page. **Oh** and why in the world are you passing values into `$window.height()`? Are you trying to make the image itself 800 by 600? In that case, you don't need the `$window` part at all, just use this: `$(this).height(600).width(800);`.

Comment: Im not sure why I did that. I was just trying becuase it wasnt working. The site is updated with your newest code. The idea is to have the div expand to 800 x 600.

Comment: Matt, thanks for your time man...but its still doing the same thing.

Comment: @Greg: no problem, I see what the problem is. In the callback, `this` does not point to the DOM element. Revising now.

Comment: @Greg: nailed it. See my edit. FWIW, I don't think this is a well-written jQuery plugin.

Comment: glad you are a genius! - Not to over step my bounds...have you any idea why this doesn't work in firefox?

Comment: @Greg: It doesn't work in Chrome, either. You have a syntax error in your code on the live site. `$(this).rotateAnimation(0, duration: 600);` is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: @Greg: you need to pull the `duration: 600` out of the `rotateAnimation` function call, put it into the same object as the other parameters (like `angle`).

Comment: @ Matt, Thanks again. I was fooling around in there with the options. I'm sitll pretty new to jquery. What's strange is....the plugin http://wilq32.adobeair.pl/jQueryRotate/Wilq32.jQueryRotate.html seems to work on the demo page....i wonder if i can shift things around to make it work...