# How to zoom div content using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a parent `<div>`. Inside that I place some text and images. Now I need to zoom to a  particular portion of that parent `<div>`. Is it possible?

Comment: could you please provide jsfiddle link.

Comment: related/duplicate: [JavaScript Zoom whole Div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064632/javascript-zoom-whole-div), 
[How to zoom an entire div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222198/how-to-zoom-an-entire-div)

Comment: see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/D7cn8/

Comment: that's not generally solvable, imagine you have to pictures in your div, each taking 50% width, what do you expect to happen on zoom?

Comment: Ooooh, see my [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/a5JkP/5/embedded/result/) too !!

Comment: how you want to zoom that particular portion on mouse hover or on clicking any zoom button or on page load?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you want that image to be zoomed on mouse hover :

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$('#div img').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).animate({ 'zoom': 1.2 }, 400);
    },
    function() {
        $(this).animate({ 'zoom': 1 }, 400);
    });
});
```

​or you may do like this if zoom in and out buttons are used :

```
$("#ZoomIn").click(ZoomIn());

$("#ZoomOut").click(ZoomOut());

function ZoomIn (event) {

    $("#div img").width(
        $("#div img").width() * 1.2
    );

    $("#div img").height(
        $("#div img").height() * 1.2
    );
},

function  ZoomOut (event) {

    $("#div img").width(
        $("#imgDtls").width() * 0.5
    );

    $("#div img").height(
        $("#div img").height() * 0.5
    );
}
```

Comment: The question was about a div, not an image right? this wont work

Comment: @Pablo it works if you put a little effort and adapt it to your case.

Comment: @Pablo if you want that with a div you can modify the code and try that works above code is to zoom the image in the div

Comment: `zoom` is not supported on Firefox.

Answer (score 13):

@Gadde - your answer was very helpful. Thank you! I needed a "Maps"-like zoom for a div and was able to produce the feel I needed with your post. My criteria included the need to have the click repeat and continue to zoom out/in with each click. Below is my final result.

```
    var currentZoom = 1.0;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btn_ZoomIn').click(
            function () {
                $('#divName').animate({ 'zoom': currentZoom += .1 }, 'slow');
            })
        $('#btn_ZoomOut').click(
            function () {
                $('#divName').animate({ 'zoom': currentZoom -= .1 }, 'slow');
            })
        $('#btn_ZoomReset').click(
            function () {
                currentZoom = 1.0
                $('#divName').animate({ 'zoom': 1 }, 'slow');
            })
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 $('image').animate({ 'zoom': 1}, 400);
```

Answer (score 0):

Used zoom-master/jquery.zoom.js. The zoom for the image worked perfectly. Here is a link to the page.
http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#ex1').zoom();

    });
</script>
```