# Smooth zoom mobile div elements

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, zooming, hammer.js

I have a webpage where I show some PDFs converted in HTML5 with [this awesome tool called pdf2htmlEX](https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX).

In the same page I make a navigation bar.
If I use mobile devices and I zoom with pinch-to-zoom gesture, the device apply zoom to all elements with navigation bar included.

I would like to make only the html-pdf content zoomable with pinch-to-zoom on mobile devices. I wrapped the content inside a div with id "content-container" and I tried some JS libraries like [HammerJS](http://hammerjs.github.io/) (results with bad bad mobile performance) and [iScroll-5](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-5) but I can't figure it out.

I checked out [OpenStreetMaps mobile](https://www.openstreetmap.org) website that have some fixed elements and zoomable contents.

Have anyone implemented with good result this feature?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

See this similar question: [How to zoom div content using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13931225/how-to-zoom-div-content-using-jquery)

Basically you can use `$('#divName').animate({ 'zoom': zoomlevel }, 'slow');` to get the effect you like using zoom control buttons.

A good plugin that is very flexible to use zoom is http://jaukia.github.io/zoomooz/

Comment: Hello, thank you for you response. I edit my question: it was not clear that the problem I'm trying to solve is only with pinch-to-zoom gesture on mobile devices.

Comment: Ok, still the library zoomooz supports that functionality, so take a look :)