# How to make an image grow inside of its container to create a zoom effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://darrenbachan.com/

I'm trying to make it where when I hover over a project the img zooms in. I tried using this:

```
.grow { transition: all .2s ease-in-out; }
.grow:hover { transform: scale(1.1); }
```

But when I put it on  it makes the entire container to grow. I even tried putting the class grow on the span that holds the image but it does the same thing.

I then tried:

```
.grow { 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 2s ease;
    -o-transition: all 2s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 2s ease;
    transition: all 2s ease;
}
.grow:hover { 
    /*transform: scale(1.1);*/ 
    background-size: 150%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

But this doesn't work either. It scales the background from the top left corner and has no easing.

How can I modify the code to achieve the zoom effect I'm looking for?

Comment: Put inside a container wrapper and your done ;)

Comment: Check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/s3hWj/4/ , I believe this is exactly the effect you need here.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13931225/how-to-zoom-div-content-using-jquery

Comment: You misspelled the `scale(1.1);`, should be a comma between the numbers, not a dot.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, your images seems to be doing what you want them to do, unless you want a bigger zoom in which case you want to adjust your background size:

```
.grow:hover {
    background-size: 130% 130%;
    opacity:1.0;
}
```

or to the zoom level of your choice