# jQuery zoom in and out scrollable div, eliminate scroll when all contents visible

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, zooming

I have created a page that contains a variety of columns.  These columns can end up off the side of the screen which is the intended default position.  However, I want to be able to give users the option of zooming out so that all the columns would be visible.  I have followed another stack overflow question about how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13931225/how-to-zoom-div-content-using-jquery), but it only zooms the visible part of the div and not the rest of the contents.

```js
// Set initial zoom level
var zoom_level = 100;

// Click events
$('.zoom-in').click(function() {
    zoom_page(10, $(this))
});
$('.zoom-out').click(function() {
    zoom_page(-10, $(this))
});
$('.zoom-reset').click(function() {
    zoom_page(0, $(this))
});

// Zoom function
function zoom_page(step, trigger) {
    // Zoom just to steps in or out
    if (zoom_level >= 200 && step > 0 || zoom_level <= 30 && step < 0) return;

    // Set / reset zoom
    if (step == 0) zoom_level = 100;
    else zoom_level = zoom_level + step;

    var scale = zoom_level / 100;

    // Set page zoom via CSS
    $('.board-canvas').css({
        moztransform: 'scale(scale, scale)', // Moz-browsers 
        transform: 'scale(' + (scale) + ')', // set zoom
        transformOrigin: '50% 0' // set transform scale base
    });

    // Adjust page to zoom width
    if (zoom_level > 100) $('.board-canvass').css({
        width: (zoom_level * 1.2) + '%'
    });
    else $('body').css({
        width: '100%'
    });

    // Activate / deactivate trigger (use CSS to make them look different)
    if (zoom_level >= 20 || zoom_level <= 40) trigger.addClass('disabled');
    else trigger.parents('ul').find('.disabled').removeClass('disabled');
    if (zoom_level != 100) $('#zoom_reset').removeClass('disabled');
    else $('#zoom_reset').addClass('disabled');
}

function updateLists(element, columnId) {
    //doSomething

}



$('.btn').on("click", function(event) {
    $("*").css("cursor", "progress");
});
```

```css
.card {
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.portfolio-container {
   background-color: #1d3c5c;
}

.card-member-span {
    padding-right: 1em;
}

.project-dialog {
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #1d3c5c;
}

.portfolio-dialog {
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.dialog {
    display: none;
}

.project-block {
    padding-left: 0.25em;
    padding-bottom: 0.25em;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    cursor: pointer;
    /*     -webkit-user-select: none; */
    /*     -moz-user-select: none; */
    /*     -ms-user-select: none; */
    /*     user-select: none; */
    /*     border-radius: 1em; */
}

.project-block.focus,
.project-block:focus,
.project-block:hover {
    color: #333;
}

.project-block-primary {
    color: #1d3c5c;
    background-color: #ddd;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.list-cards {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin: 0 4px;
    padding: 0 4px;
    z-index: 1;
    min-height: 0;
    border-radius: 1em;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.portfolio-card {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 3em;
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: #000;
    padding-left: 3px;
}

.list-card-members {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.list-card-section {}

.list-card-project-section {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.list-card {
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    /*  background-color: #5b5353; */
    background-color: #1d3c5c;
    border-radius: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Add rounded corners to the top left and the top right corner of the image */

img {
    vertical-align: inherit;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a deeper shadow */

.card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

/* Add some padding inside the card container */

.container {
    padding: 2px 16px;
}

#board {
    /*     user-select: none; */
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

/* .list-header-target { */

/*     cursor: pointer; */

/*     position: absolute; */

/*     top: 0; */

/*     left: 0; */

/*     right: 0; */

/*     bottom: 0; */

/* } */

.list {
    /*  background-color: #5b5353; */
    background-color: #1d3c5c;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    white-space: normal;
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.board-menu-container,
.list {
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
}

.list-wrapper {
    width: 270px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    min-height: 600px;
}

.search-filter {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    display: none;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.search-filter-block {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.search-filter-tag-block {
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.search-filter-select {
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.search-colour-button {
    color: white;
    padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 1em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
    -moz-border-radius: 1em;
}

.search-colour-button.active {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px #b3b3b3, inset 0 5px 10px #e6e6e6;
    font-weight: 800;
}

.project-card {
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-radius: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*  background-color: #5b5353; */
    background-color: #1d3c5c;
    min-height: 10%;
    max-height: 90%;
    min-width: 10%;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 1em;
}

.project-card-content {
    /*     padding: 0.5em; */
    background-color: #fff;
}

.portfolio-card-title {
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0.5em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.portfolio-projects-title {
    font-weight: 600;
}

.search-tags-form {
    margin: 4px 2px;
}

.list-header {
    color: #ddd;
}

.list-header-name-assist {
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
}

hr {
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
}

.portfolio-dialog {
    background-color: #1d3c5c;
    color: #fff;
}

.portfolio-dialog-content {
    background-color: #1d3c5c;
    color: #ffffff;
}

dl {
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.bg-dark {
    color: #333333;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.portfolio-card-content {
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    border-radius: 1em;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.fps-tag-block {
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
}

.portfolio-icon-list {
    color: #000;
}

.ui-dialog {
    /*  background-color: #5b5353; */
    background-color: #1d3c5c;
}

.ui-dialog-titlebar {
    /*  background-color: #5b5353; */
    background-color: #1d3c5c;
    color: #ddd;
    border: 0px;
}

.ui-dialog-buttonpane {
    background-color: #1d3c5c;
    color: #ddd;
    border: 0px;
}

.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-title {
    text-align: center;
}

.ui-dialog-buttonset {
    color: #1d3c5c;
}

.ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
    color: #1d3c5c;
    content: "X";
}

.ui-widget-content {
    /*     background-color: #1d3c5c; */
}

.ui-widget-content a {
    color: #333333;
}

.portfolio-toggle:before {
    /*     content: "\25b2"; */
    content: "▸";
}

.portfolio-toggle.collapsed:before {
    /*     content:  "\25bc"; */
    content: "▾";
}

.project-block-rounded {
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    padding: 0.25em;
    margin: 0.25em;
}

.open-portfolio-dialog-btn {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.portfolio-overview-btn {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.media-capture-btn {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#search-filter-block {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dl-horizontal dt {
    text-align: left;
}

.dl-horizontal dd {
    width: auto;
}

.portfolio-card-filter {
    padding-left: 1em;
}

.portfolio-metadata {
    color: #000;
}

.portfolio-overview {
    color: #000;
}

.fixed-header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0em;
    background-color: #1d3c5c;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 270px;
    text-align: center;
}

.sortable-list {
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.search-highlighter {
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.portfolio-specific-btn {
    padding-right: 0.5em;
}

hr {
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/fcc45c3f3f.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid" id="core-content">

    <form name="search-filter-form" method="POST" class="">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="text-center col-xs-2">
                        <i class="fa fa-search-plus zoom-in" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-search-minus zoom-out" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center col-xs-1">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-primary ">Reset</a>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>


    <div id="loading-msg" style="display: none;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="spacer-sml"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="spacer-sml"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
            <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-5x fa-fw"></i>
            <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
            <p>Loading...</p>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="portfolio-container" class="container-fluid portfolio-container" style="">

        <div class="spacer-sml"></div>
        <form action="#" id="portfolio-form" name="portfolio-form" method="POST" class="">

            <div class="board-canvas">
                <div id="board" class="u-fancy-scrollbar js-no-higher-edits js-list-sortable ui-sortable">

                    <div class="js-list list-wrapper ">
                        <div class="list js-list-content">
                            <div class="list-header js-list-header u-clearfix is-menu-shown">
                                <div class="list-header-target js-editing-target"></div>
                                <h4 class="list-header-name-assist js-list-name-assist text-center" dir="auto">
                                    Awaiting Approval
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="sortable-list ui-sortable" data-column-id="awaitapprove" data-column-value="awaitapprove Awaiting Approval">


                                <div data-portfolio-path="Tennis" data-portfolio-id="5ac752e61c99a112046cf391" class="list-card js-member-droppable is-covered ui-droppable search-display-block sfilter ui-sortable-handle">

                                    <div class="list-card-cover js-card-cover portfolio-card" style="background-color: #02bf6f;
              
             color: #000000; ">

                                        <div class="portfolio-card-filter-block">
                                            <div class="portfolio-card-title portfolio-card-filter-heading ">
                                                <div class="accordion-toggle collapsed portfolio-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#portfolioAccordion" data-target="#portfolio5ac752e61c99a112046cf391" aria-expanded="false">
                                                    <span class="portfolio-accordion"></span>

                                                    <i class="fa fa-user-circle " aria-hidden="true" title="You are a member of this portfolio"></i>&nbsp;

                                                    <span class="archiware-archive-state" data-portfolio-path="Tennis" data-portfolio-id="5ac752e61c99a112046cf391"><i class="fa fa-database" aria-hidden="true" title="Has been archived"></i></span>                                                    Tennis
                                                    <span class="text-right"></span>

                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            
                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                    
                                    <hr>
                                    <div class="list-card-details text-center">
                                        <div class="list-card-members js-list-card-members">
                                            <div class="portfolio-icon-list " data-example-id="portfolio-icon-list">
                                                <div class="btn-group portfolio-specific-btn portfolio-overview-btn" title="Portfolio Overview">
                                                    <a href="#" class="portfolio-overview">
                        <i class="fa fa-eye fa-1-5-font-size" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="btn-group portfolio-specific-btn portfolio-checklist-btn" title="Portfolio Checklist">
                                                    <a href="#" class="portfolio-checklist">
                        <i class="fa fa-list fa-1-5-font-size" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="btn-group portfolio-specific-btn open-portfolio-metadata-btn" data-dialog-id="5ac752e61c99a112046cf391" title="Portfolio Metadata">
                                                    <a href="#" class="portfolio-metadata">
                    <i class="fa fa-file-text fa-1-5-font-size" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="btn-group portfolio-specific-btn open-portfolio-forum-btn" data-dialog-id="5ac752e61c99a112046cf391" title="Portfolio Forum">
                                                    <a href="#" class="portfolio-forum">
                        <i class="fa fa-commenting fa-1-5-font-size" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="list-card-project-section">

                                            <div class="project-block project-block-primary open-project-dialog-btn" name="open-project-dialog-btn" data-dialog-id="project-dialog-motion-5ac752e61c99a112046cf391">
                                                Motion Sports: <span class="badge">1</span>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="dialog project-dialog project-dialog-motion" name="project-dialog-motion" id="project-dialog-motion-5ac752e61c99a112046cf391" title="Awaiting Approval Motion Sports">

                                                <div class="project-card">
                                                    <div class="project-card-content">

                                                        <div class="fps-tag-block fps-tag-Motion">
                                                            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                                                                <dt class="text-left">Storyline:</dt>
                                                                <dd>Motion</dd>
                                                            </dl>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="fps-tag-block fps-tag-">
                                                            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                                                                <dt class="text-left">Comment:</dt>
                                                                <dd></dd>
                                                            </dl>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="fps-tag-block fps-tag-1">
                                                            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                                                                <dt class="text-left">Version:</dt>
                                                                <dd>1</dd>
                                                            </dl>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="fps-tag-block fps-tag-createddate">
                                                            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                                                                <dt class="text-left">Created:</dt>
                                                                <dd>6-4-2018</dd>
                                                            </dl>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="fps-tag-block fps-tag-inprogress">
                                                            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                                                                <dt class="text-left">Status:</dt>
                                                                <dd>In Progress</dd>
                                                            </dl>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="fps-tag-block fps-tag-{day=11, month=4, year=2018}">
                                                            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                                                                <dt class="text-left">Completed Date:</dt>
                                                                <dd>11-4-2018</dd>
                                                            </dl>
                                                        </div>

                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>

                                            

                                            
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="js-list list-wrapper ">
                        <div class="list js-list-content">
                            <div class="list-header js-list-header u-clearfix is-menu-shown">
                                <div class="list-header-target js-editing-target"></div>
                                <h4 class="list-header-name-assist js-list-name-assist text-center" dir="auto">
                                    Approved
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="sortable-list ui-sortable" data-column-id="approved" data-column-value="approved Approved">

                                <div class="ui-sortable-handle">

                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="js-list list-wrapper ">
                        <div class="list js-list-content">
                            <div class="list-header js-list-header u-clearfix is-menu-shown">
                                <div class="list-header-target js-editing-target"></div>
                                <h4 class="list-header-name-assist js-list-name-assist text-center" dir="auto">
                                    Editing in Progress
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="sortable-list ui-sortable" data-column-id="editinprog" data-column-value="editinprog Editing in Progress">

                                <div class="ui-sortable-handle">

                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="js-list list-wrapper ">
                        <div class="list js-list-content">
                            <div class="list-header js-list-header u-clearfix is-menu-shown">
                                <div class="list-header-target js-editing-target"></div>
                                <h4 class="list-header-name-assist js-list-name-assist text-center" dir="auto">
                                    Awaiting Graphics
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="sortable-list ui-sortable" data-column-id="awaitgraph" data-column-value="awaitgraph Awaiting Graphics">

                                <div class="ui-sortable-handle">

                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="js-list list-wrapper ">
                        <div class="list js-list-content">
                            <div class="list-header js-list-header u-clearfix is-menu-shown">
                                <div class="list-header-target js-editing-target"></div>
                                <h4 class="list-header-name-assist js-list-name-assist text-center" dir="auto">
                                    Ready for Dubbing
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="sortable-list ui-sortable" data-column-id="readydubbing" data-column-value="readydubbing Ready for Dubbing">

                                <div class="ui-sortable-handle">

                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="js-list list-wrapper ">
                        <div class="list js-list-content">
                            <div class="list-header js-list-header u-clearfix is-menu-shown">
                                <div class="list-header-target js-editing-target"></div>
                                <h4 class="list-header-name-assist js-list-name-assist text-center" dir="auto">
                                    Ready for Grading
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="sortable-list ui-sortable" data-column-id="readygrading" data-column-value="readygrading Ready for Grading">

                                <div class="ui-sortable-handle">

                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="js-list list-wrapper ">
                        <div class="list js-list-content">
                            <div class="list-header js-list-header u-clearfix is-menu-shown">
                                <div class="list-header-target js-editing-target"></div>
                                <h4 class="list-header-name-assist js-list-name-assist text-center" dir="auto">
                                    Completed
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="sortable-list ui-sortable" data-column-id="completed" data-column-value="completed Completed">

                                <div class="ui-sortable-handle">

                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="js-list list-wrapper ">
                        <div class="list js-list-content">
                            <div class="list-header js-list-header u-clearfix is-menu-shown">
                                <div class="list-header-target js-editing-target"></div>
                                <h4 class="list-header-name-assist js-list-name-assist text-center" dir="auto">
                                    Not Approved -Do Not Distribute
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="sortable-list ui-sortable" data-column-id="notapproved" data-column-value="notapproved Not Approved -Do Not Distribute">

                                <div class="ui-sortable-handle">

                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="spacer-sml"></div>

        </form>

    </div>

</div>
```

As you can see the div zooms but only to the level of the default displayed content.  I want to be able to zoom out enough, so that the scroll bar disappears.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your are scaling only visually, but actual DOM element size hasn't been changed. You'll need to write custom JS to resize actual column width, font size, etc. for zoom-in and zoom-our events.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought of it that way.  As you can zoom out and see the full contents using the browsers zoom, I figured there must be a way to do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just trying to enable a basic zoom effect that results in scroll behavior change once all elements become visible, then I think you just need to apply the transform to a wrapper element inside your scrollable element.

In the snippet below, I just added a new `#zoom-wrapper` `div` inside your `#board` `div` and updated your `zoom_page` function to transform `#zoom-wrapper` (I also set the `transform-origin: 0 0` so that you can see the zoom eliminate the scrolling more easily - not sure if you had something else in mind with how you were trying to reset the origin).

Hopefully this gets you pointed in the right direction.

```js
// Set initial zoom level
var zoom_level = 100;

// Click events
$('.zoom-in').click(function() {
    zoom_page(10, $(this))
});
$('.zoom-out').click(function() {
    zoom_page(-10, $(this))
});
$('.zoom-reset').click(function() {
    zoom_page(0, $(this))
});

// Zoom function
function zoom_page(step, trigger) {
    // Zoom just to steps in or out
    if (zoom_level >= 200 && step > 0 || zoom_level <= 30 && step < 0) return;

    // Set / reset zoom
    if (step == 0) zoom_level = 100;
    else zoom_level = zoom_level + step;

    var scale = zoom_level / 100;

    // Set page zoom via CSS
    $('#zoom-wrapper').css({
        'transform': 'scale(' + (scale) + ')', // set zoom
        'transform-origin': '0 0'
    });

    // Adjust page to zoom width
    if (zoom_level > 100) $('#zoom-wrapper').css({
        width: (zoom_level * 1.2) + '%'
    });
    else $('body').css({
        width: '100%'
    });

    // Activate / deactivate trigger (use CSS to make them look different)
    if (zoom_level >= 20 || zoom_level <= 40) trigger.addClass('disabled');
    else trigger.parents('ul').find('.disabled').removeClass('disabled');
    if (zoom_level != 100) $('#zoom_reset').removeClass('disabled');
    else $('#zoom_reset').addClass('disabled');
}

function updateLists(element, columnId) {
    //doSomething

}



$('.btn').on("click", function(event) {
    $("*").css("cursor", "progress");
});
```

```css
.card {
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.portfolio-container {
   background-color: #1d3c5c;
}

.card-member-span {
    padding-right: 1em;
}

.project-dialog {
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #1d3c5c;
}

.portfolio-dialog {
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.dialog {
    display: none;
}

.project-block {
    padding-left: 0.25em;
    padding-bottom: 0.25em;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    cursor: pointer;
    /*     -webkit-user-select: none; */
    /*     -moz-user-select: none; */
    /*     -ms-user-select: none; */
    /*     user-select: none; */
    /*     border-radius: 1em; */
}

.project-block.focus,
.project-block:focus,
.project-block:hover {
    color: #333;
}

.project-block-primary {
    color: #1d3c5c;
    background-color: #ddd;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.list-cards {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin: 0 4px;
    padding: 0 4px;
    z-index: 1;
    min-height: 0;
    border-radius: 1em;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.portfolio-card {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 3em;
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: #000;
    padding-left: 3px;
}

.list-card-members {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.list-card-section {}

.list-card-project-section {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.list-card {
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    /*  background-color: #5b5353; */
    background-color: #1d3c5c;
    border-radius: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Add rounded corners to the top left and the top right corner of the image */

img {
    vertical-align: inherit;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a deeper shadow */

.card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

/* Add some padding inside the card container */

.container {
    padding: 2px 16px;
}

#board {
    /*     user-select: none; */
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

/* .list-header-target { */

/*     cursor: pointer; */

/*     position: absolute; */

/*     top: 0; */

/*     left: 0; */

/*     right: 0; */

/*     bottom: 0; */

/* } */

.list {
    /*  background-color: #5b5353; */
    background-color: #1d3c5c;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    white-space: normal;
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.board-menu-container,
.list {
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
}

.list-wrapper {
    width: 270px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    min-height: 600px;
}

.search-filter {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    display: none;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.search-filter-block {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.search-filter-tag-block {
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.search-filter-select {
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.search-colour-button {
    color: white;
    padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 1em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
    -moz-border-radius: 1em;
}

.search-colour-button.active {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px #b3b3b3, inset 0 5px 10px #e6e6e6;
    font-weight: 800;
}

.project-card {
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-radius: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*  background-color: #5b5353; */
    background-color: #1d3c5c;
    min-height: 10%;
    max-height: 90%;
    min-width: 10%;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 1em;
}

.project-card-content {
    /*     padding: 0.5em; */
    background-color: #fff;
}

.portfolio-card-title {
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0.5em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.portfolio-projects-title {
    font-weight: 600;
}

.search-tags-form {
    margin: 4px 2px;
}

.list-header {
    color: #ddd;
}

.list-header-name-assist {
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
}

hr {
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
}

.portfolio-dialog {
    background-color: #1d3c5c;
    color: #fff;
}

.portfolio-dialog-content {
    background-color: #1d3c5c;
    color: #ffffff;
}

dl {
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.bg-dark {
    color: #333333;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.portfolio-card-content {
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    border-radius: 1em;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.fps-tag-block {
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
}

.portfolio-icon-list {
    color: #000;
}

.ui-dialog {
    /*  background-color: #5b5353; */
    background-color: #1d3c5c;
}

.ui-dialog-titlebar {
    /*  background-color: #5b5353; */
    background-color: #1d3c5c;
    color: #ddd;
    border: 0px;
}

.ui-dialog-buttonpane {
    background-color: #1d3c5c;
    color: #ddd;
    border: 0px;
}

.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-title {
    text-align: center;
}

.ui-dialog-buttonset {
    color: #1d3c5c;
}

.ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
    color: #1d3c5c;
    content: "X";
}

.ui-widget-content {
    /*     background-color: #1d3c5c; */
}

.ui-widget-content a {
    color: #333333;
}

.portfolio-toggle:before {
    /*     content: "\25b2"; */
    content: "▸";
}

.portfolio-toggle.collapsed:before {
    /*     content:  "\25bc"; */
    content: "▾";
}

.project-block-rounded {
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    padding: 0.25em;
    margin: 0.25em;
}

.open-portfolio-dialog-btn {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.portfolio-overview-btn {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.media-capture-btn {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#search-filter-block {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dl-horizontal dt {
    text-align: left;
}

.dl-horizontal dd {
    width: auto;
}

.portfolio-card-filter {
    padding-left: 1em;
}

.portfolio-metadata {
    color: #000;
}

.portfolio-overview {
    color: #000;
}

.fixed-header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0em;
    background-color: #1d3c5c;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 270px;
    text-align: center;
}

.sortable-list {
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.search-highlighter {
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.portfolio-specific-btn {
    padding-right: 0.5em;
}

hr {
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/fcc45c3f3f.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid" id="core-content">

    <form name="search-filter-form" method="POST" class="">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="text-center col-xs-2">
                        <i class="fa fa-search-plus zoom-in" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-search-minus zoom-out" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center col-xs-1">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-primary ">Reset</a>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>


    <div id="loading-msg" style="display: none;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="spacer-sml"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="spacer-sml"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
            <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-5x fa-fw"></i>
            <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
            <p>Loading...</p>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="portfolio-container" class="container-fluid portfolio-container" style="">

        <div class="spacer-sml"></div>
        <form action="#" id="portfolio-form" name="portfolio-form" method="POST" class="">

            <div class="board-canvas">
                <div id="board" class="u-fancy-scrollbar js-no-higher-edits js-list-sortable ui-sortable">
                  <div id="zoom-wrapper">
                    <div class="js-list list-wrapper ">
                        <div class="list js-list-content">
                            <div class="list-header js-list-header u-clearfix is-menu-shown">
                                <div class="list-header-target js-editing-target"></div>
                                <h4 class="list-header-name-assist js-list-name-assist text-center" dir="auto">
                                    Awaiting Approval
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="sortable-list ui-sortable" data-column-id="awaitapprove" data-column-value="awaitapprove Awaiting Approval">


                                <div data-portfolio-path="Tennis" data-portfolio-id="5ac752e61c99a112046cf391" class="list-card js-member-droppable is-covered ui-droppable search-display-block sfilter ui-sortable-handle">

                                    <div class="list-card-cover js-card-cover portfolio-card" style="background-color: #02bf6f;
              
             color: #000000; ">

                                        <div class="portfolio-card-filter-block">
                                            <div class="portfolio-card-title portfolio-card-filter-heading ">
                                                <div class="accordion-toggle collapsed portfolio-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#portfolioAccordion" data-target="#portfolio5ac752e61c99a112046cf391" aria-expanded="false">
                                                    <span class="portfolio-accordion"></span>

                                                    <i class="fa fa-user-circle " aria-hidden="true" title="You are a member of this portfolio"></i>&nbsp;

                                                    <span class="archiware-archive-state" data-portfolio-path="Tennis" data-portfolio-id="5ac752e61c99a112046cf391"><i class="fa fa-database" aria-hidden="true" title="Has been archived"></i></span>                                                    Tennis
                                                    <span class="text-right"></span>

                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            
                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                    
                                    <hr>
                                    <div class="list-card-details text-center">
                                        <div class="list-card-members js-list-card-members">
                                            <div class="portfolio-icon-list " data-example-id="portfolio-icon-list">
                                                <div class="btn-group portfolio-specific-btn portfolio-overview-btn" title="Portfolio Overview">
                                                    <a href="#" class="portfolio-overview">
                        <i class="fa fa-eye fa-1-5-font-size" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="btn-group portfolio-specific-btn portfolio-checklist-btn" title="Portfolio Checklist">
                                                    <a href="#" class="portfolio-checklist">
                        <i class="fa fa-list fa-1-5-font-size" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="btn-group portfolio-specific-btn open-portfolio-metadata-btn" data-dialog-id="5ac752e61c99a112046cf391" title="Portfolio Metadata">
                                                    <a href="#" class="portfolio-metadata">
                    <i class="fa fa-file-text fa-1-5-font-size" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="btn-group portfolio-specific-btn open-portfolio-forum-btn" data-dialog-id="5ac752e61c99a112046cf391" title="Portfolio Forum">
                                                    <a href="#" class="portfolio-forum">
                        <i class="fa fa-commenting fa-1-5-font-size" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="list-card-project-section">

                                            <div class="project-block project-block-primary open-project-dialog-btn" name="open-project-dialog-btn" data-dialog-id="project-dialog-motion-5ac752e61c99a112046cf391">
                                                Motion Sports: <span class="badge">1</span>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="dialog project-dialog project-dialog-motion" name="project-dialog-motion" id="project-dialog-motion-5ac752e61c99a112046cf391" title="Awaiting Approval Motion Sports">

                                                <div class="project-card">
                                                    <div class="project-card-content">

                                                        <div class="fps-tag-block fps-tag-Motion">
                                                            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                                                                <dt class="text-left">Storyline:</dt>
                                                                <dd>Motion</dd>
                                                            </dl>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="fps-tag-block fps-tag-">
                                                            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                                                                <dt class="text-left">Comment:</dt>
                                                                <dd></dd>
                                                            </dl>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="fps-tag-block fps-tag-1">
                                                            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                                                                <dt class="text-left">Version:</dt>
                                                                <dd>1</dd>
                                                            </dl>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="fps-tag-block fps-tag-createddate">
                                                            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                                                                <dt class="text-left">Created:</dt>
                                                                <dd>6-4-2018</dd>
                                                            </dl>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="fps-tag-block fps-tag-inprogress">
                                                            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                                                                <dt class="text-left">Status:</dt>
                                                                <dd>In Progress</dd>
                                                            </dl>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="fps-tag-block fps-tag-{day=11, month=4, year=2018}">
                                                            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                                                                <dt class="text-left">Completed Date:</dt>
                                                                <dd>11-4-2018</dd>
                                                            </dl>
                                                        </div>

                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>

                                            

                                            
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="js-list list-wrapper ">
                        <div class="list js-list-content">
                            <div class="list-header js-list-header u-clearfix is-menu-shown">
                                <div class="list-header-target js-editing-target"></div>
                                <h4 class="list-header-name-assist js-list-name-assist text-center" dir="auto">
                                    Approved
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="sortable-list ui-sortable" data-column-id="approved" data-column-value="approved Approved">

                                <div class="ui-sortable-handle">

                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="js-list list-wrapper ">
                        <div class="list js-list-content">
                            <div class="list-header js-list-header u-clearfix is-menu-shown">
                                <div class="list-header-target js-editing-target"></div>
                                <h4 class="list-header-name-assist js-list-name-assist text-center" dir="auto">
                                    Editing in Progress
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="sortable-list ui-sortable" data-column-id="editinprog" data-column-value="editinprog Editing in Progress">

                                <div class="ui-sortable-handle">

                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="js-list list-wrapper ">
                        <div class="list js-list-content">
                            <div class="list-header js-list-header u-clearfix is-menu-shown">
                                <div class="list-header-target js-editing-target"></div>
                                <h4 class="list-header-name-assist js-list-name-assist text-center" dir="auto">
                                    Awaiting Graphics
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="sortable-list ui-sortable" data-column-id="awaitgraph" data-column-value="awaitgraph Awaiting Graphics">

                                <div class="ui-sortable-handle">

                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="js-list list-wrapper ">
                        <div class="list js-list-content">
                            <div class="list-header js-list-header u-clearfix is-menu-shown">
                                <div class="list-header-target js-editing-target"></div>
                                <h4 class="list-header-name-assist js-list-name-assist text-center" dir="auto">
                                    Ready for Dubbing
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="sortable-list ui-sortable" data-column-id="readydubbing" data-column-value="readydubbing Ready for Dubbing">

                                <div class="ui-sortable-handle">

                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="js-list list-wrapper ">
                        <div class="list js-list-content">
                            <div class="list-header js-list-header u-clearfix is-menu-shown">
                                <div class="list-header-target js-editing-target"></div>
                                <h4 class="list-header-name-assist js-list-name-assist text-center" dir="auto">
                                    Ready for Grading
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="sortable-list ui-sortable" data-column-id="readygrading" data-column-value="readygrading Ready for Grading">

                                <div class="ui-sortable-handle">

                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="js-list list-wrapper ">
                        <div class="list js-list-content">
                            <div class="list-header js-list-header u-clearfix is-menu-shown">
                                <div class="list-header-target js-editing-target"></div>
                                <h4 class="list-header-name-assist js-list-name-assist text-center" dir="auto">
                                    Completed
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="sortable-list ui-sortable" data-column-id="completed" data-column-value="completed Completed">

                                <div class="ui-sortable-handle">

                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="js-list list-wrapper ">
                        <div class="list js-list-content">
                            <div class="list-header js-list-header u-clearfix is-menu-shown">
                                <div class="list-header-target js-editing-target"></div>
                                <h4 class="list-header-name-assist js-list-name-assist text-center" dir="auto">
                                    Not Approved -Do Not Distribute
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="sortable-list ui-sortable" data-column-id="notapproved" data-column-value="notapproved Not Approved -Do Not Distribute">

                                <div class="ui-sortable-handle">

                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="spacer-sml"></div>

        </form>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Had to make a slight adjustment to keep the contents on the left just after the scale transformOrigin: "0 0"

Answer (score 2):

Apply the transform css on container-fluid

```
$('.container-fluid').css({
        moztransform: 'scale(scale, scale)', // Moz-browsers 
        transform: 'scale(' + (scale) + ')', // set zoom
        transformOrigin: '50% 0' // set transform scale base
});
```

```js
// Set initial zoom level
var zoom_level = 100;

// Click events
$('.zoom-in').click(function() {
    zoom_page(10, $(this))
});
$('.zoom-out').click(function() {
    zoom_page(-10, $(this))
});
$('.zoom-reset').click(function() {
    zoom_page(0, $(this))
});

// Zoom function
function zoom_page(step, trigger) {
    // Zoom just to steps in or out
    if (zoom_level >= 200 && step > 0 || zoom_level <= 30 && step < 0) return;

    // Set / reset zoom
    if (step == 0) zoom_level = 100;
    else zoom_level = zoom_level + step;

    var scale = zoom_level / 100;

    // Set page zoom via CSS
        $('.container-fluid').css({
        moztransform: 'scale(scale, scale)', // Moz-browsers 
        transform: 'scale(' + (scale) + ')', // set zoom
        transformOrigin: '50% 0' // set transform scale base
        });

    // Adjust page to zoom width
    if (zoom_level > 100) $('.board-canvass').css({
        width: (zoom_level * 1.2) + '%'
    });
    else $('body').css({
        width: '100%'
    });

    // Activate / deactivate trigger (use CSS to make them look different)
    if (zoom_level >= 20 || zoom_level <= 40) trigger.addClass('disabled');
    else trigger.parents('ul').find('.disabled').removeClass('disabled');
    if (zoom_level != 100) $('#zoom_reset').removeClass('disabled');
    else $('#zoom_reset').addClass('disabled');
}

function updateLists(element, columnId) {
    //doSomething

}



$('.btn').on("click", function(event) {
    $("*").css("cursor", "progress");
});
```

```css
.card {
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.portfolio-container {
   background-color: #1d3c5c;
}

.card-member-span {
    padding-right: 1em;
}

.project-dialog {
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #1d3c5c;
}

.portfolio-dialog {
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.dialog {
    display: none;
}

.project-block {
    padding-left: 0.25em;
    padding-bottom: 0.25em;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    cursor: pointer;
    /*     -webkit-user-select: none; */
    /*     -moz-user-select: none; */
    /*     -ms-user-select: none; */
    /*     user-select: none; */
    /*     border-radius: 1em; */
}

.project-block.focus,
.project-block:focus,
.project-block:hover {
    color: #333;
}

.project-block-primary {
    color: #1d3c5c;
    background-color: #ddd;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.list-cards {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin: 0 4px;
    padding: 0 4px;
    z-index: 1;
    min-height: 0;
    border-radius: 1em;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.portfolio-card {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 3em;
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: #000;
    padding-left: 3px;
}

.list-card-members {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.list-card-section {}

.list-card-project-section {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.list-card {
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    /*  background-color: #5b5353; */
    background-color: #1d3c5c;
    border-radius: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Add rounded corners to the top left and the top right corner of the image */

img {
    vertical-align: inherit;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a deeper shadow */

.card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

/* Add some padding inside the card container */

.container {
    padding: 2px 16px;
}

#board {
    /*     user-select: none; */
    display: flex;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

/* .list-header-target { */

/*     cursor: pointer; */

/*     position: absolute; */

/*     top: 0; */

/*     left: 0; */

/*     right: 0; */

/*     bottom: 0; */

/* } */

.list {
    /*  background-color: #5b5353; */
    background-color: #1d3c5c;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    white-space: normal;
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.board-menu-container,
.list {
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
}

.list-wrapper {
    width: 270px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    min-height: 600px;
}

.search-filter {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    display: none;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.search-filter-block {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.search-filter-tag-block {
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.search-filter-select {
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.search-colour-button {
    color: white;
    padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 1em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
    -moz-border-radius: 1em;
}

.search-colour-button.active {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px #b3b3b3, inset 0 5px 10px #e6e6e6;
    font-weight: 800;
}

.project-card {
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-radius: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*  background-color: #5b5353; */
    background-color: #1d3c5c;
    min-height: 10%;
    max-height: 90%;
    min-width: 10%;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 1em;
}

.project-card-content {
    /*     padding: 0.5em; */
    background-color: #fff;
}

.portfolio-card-title {
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0.5em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.portfolio-projects-title {
    font-weight: 600;
}

.search-tags-form {
    margin: 4px 2px;
}

.list-header {
    color: #ddd;
}

.list-header-name-assist {
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
}

hr {
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
}

.portfolio-dialog {
    background-color: #1d3c5c;
    color: #fff;
}

.portfolio-dialog-content {
    background-color: #1d3c5c;
    color: #ffffff;
}

dl {
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.bg-dark {
    color: #333333;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.portfolio-card-content {
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    border-radius: 1em;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.fps-tag-block {
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
}

.portfolio-icon-list {
    color: #000;
}

.ui-dialog {
    /*  background-color: #5b5353; */
    background-color: #1d3c5c;
}

.ui-dialog-titlebar {
    /*  background-color: #5b5353; */
    background-color: #1d3c5c;
    color: #ddd;
    border: 0px;
}

.ui-dialog-buttonpane {
    background-color: #1d3c5c;
    color: #ddd;
    border: 0px;
}

.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-title {
    text-align: center;
}

.ui-dialog-buttonset {
    color: #1d3c5c;
}

.ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
    color: #1d3c5c;
    content: "X";
}

.ui-widget-content {
    /*     background-color: #1d3c5c; */
}

.ui-widget-content a {
    color: #333333;
}

.portfolio-toggle:before {
    /*     content: "\25b2"; */
    content: "▸";
}

.portfolio-toggle.collapsed:before {
    /*     content:  "\25bc"; */
    content: "▾";
}

.project-block-rounded {
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    padding: 0.25em;
    margin: 0.25em;
}

.open-portfolio-dialog-btn {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.portfolio-overview-btn {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.media-capture-btn {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#search-filter-block {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dl-horizontal dt {
    text-align: left;
}

.dl-horizontal dd {
    width: auto;
}

.portfolio-card-filter {
    padding-left: 1em;
}

.portfolio-metadata {
    color: #000;
}

.portfolio-overview {
    color: #000;
}

.fixed-header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0em;
    background-color: #1d3c5c;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 270px;
    text-align: center;
}

.sortable-list {
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.search-highlighter {
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.portfolio-specific-btn {
    padding-right: 0.5em;
}

hr {
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/fcc45c3f3f.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid" id="core-content">

    <form name="search-filter-form" method="POST" class="">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="text-center col-xs-2">
                        <i class="fa fa-search-plus zoom-in" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-search-minus zoom-out" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center col-xs-1">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-primary ">Reset</a>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>


    <div id="loading-msg" style="display: none;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="spacer-sml"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="spacer-sml"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
            <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-5x fa-fw"></i>
            <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
            <p>Loading...</p>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="portfolio-container" class="container-fluid portfolio-container" style="">

        <div class="spacer-sml"></div>
        <form action="#" id="portfolio-form" name="portfolio-form" method="POST" class="">

            <div class="board-canvas">
                <div id="board" class="u-fancy-scrollbar js-no-higher-edits js-list-sortable ui-sortable">

                    <div class="js-list list-wrapper ">
                        <div class="list js-list-content">
                            <div class="list-header js-list-header u-clearfix is-menu-shown">
                                <div class="list-header-target js-editing-target"></div>
                                <h4 class="list-header-name-assist js-list-name-assist text-center" dir="auto">
                                    Awaiting Approval
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="sortable-list ui-sortable" data-column-id="awaitapprove" data-column-value="awaitapprove Awaiting Approval">


                                <div data-portfolio-path="Tennis" data-portfolio-id="5ac752e61c99a112046cf391" class="list-card js-member-droppable is-covered ui-droppable search-display-block sfilter ui-sortable-handle">

                                    <div class="list-card-cover js-card-cover portfolio-card" style="background-color: #02bf6f;
              
             color: #000000; ">

                                        <div class="portfolio-card-filter-block">
                                            <div class="portfolio-card-title portfolio-card-filter-heading ">
                                                <div class="accordion-toggle collapsed portfolio-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#portfolioAccordion" data-target="#portfolio5ac752e61c99a112046cf391" aria-expanded="false">
                                                    <span class="portfolio-accordion"></span>

                                                    <i class="fa fa-user-circle " aria-hidden="true" title="You are a member of this portfolio"></i>&nbsp;

                                                    <span class="archiware-archive-state" data-portfolio-path="Tennis" data-portfolio-id="5ac752e61c99a112046cf391"><i class="fa fa-database" aria-hidden="true" title="Has been archived"></i></span>                                                    Tennis
                                                    <span class="text-right"></span>

                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            
                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                    
                                    <hr>
                                    <div class="list-card-details text-center">
                                        <div class="list-card-members js-list-card-members">
                                            <div class="portfolio-icon-list " data-example-id="portfolio-icon-list">
                                                <div class="btn-group portfolio-specific-btn portfolio-overview-btn" title="Portfolio Overview">
                                                    <a href="#" class="portfolio-overview">
                        <i class="fa fa-eye fa-1-5-font-size" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="btn-group portfolio-specific-btn portfolio-checklist-btn" title="Portfolio Checklist">
                                                    <a href="#" class="portfolio-checklist">
                        <i class="fa fa-list fa-1-5-font-size" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="btn-group portfolio-specific-btn open-portfolio-metadata-btn" data-dialog-id="5ac752e61c99a112046cf391" title="Portfolio Metadata">
                                                    <a href="#" class="portfolio-metadata">
                    <i class="fa fa-file-text fa-1-5-font-size" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="btn-group portfolio-specific-btn open-portfolio-forum-btn" data-dialog-id="5ac752e61c99a112046cf391" title="Portfolio Forum">
                                                    <a href="#" class="portfolio-forum">
                        <i class="fa fa-commenting fa-1-5-font-size" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="list-card-project-section">

                                            <div class="project-block project-block-primary open-project-dialog-btn" name="open-project-dialog-btn" data-dialog-id="project-dialog-motion-5ac752e61c99a112046cf391">
                                                Motion Sports: <span class="badge">1</span>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="dialog project-dialog project-dialog-motion" name="project-dialog-motion" id="project-dialog-motion-5ac752e61c99a112046cf391" title="Awaiting Approval Motion Sports">

                                                <div class="project-card">
                                                    <div class="project-card-content">

                                                        <div class="fps-tag-block fps-tag-Motion">
                                                            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                                                                <dt class="text-left">Storyline:</dt>
                                                                <dd>Motion</dd>
                                                            </dl>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="fps-tag-block fps-tag-">
                                                            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                                                                <dt class="text-left">Comment:</dt>
                                                                <dd></dd>
                                                            </dl>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="fps-tag-block fps-tag-1">
                                                            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                                                                <dt class="text-left">Version:</dt>
                                                                <dd>1</dd>
                                                            </dl>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="fps-tag-block fps-tag-createddate">
                                                            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                                                                <dt class="text-left">Created:</dt>
                                                                <dd>6-4-2018</dd>
                                                            </dl>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="fps-tag-block fps-tag-inprogress">
                                                            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                                                                <dt class="text-left">Status:</dt>
                                                                <dd>In Progress</dd>
                                                            </dl>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="fps-tag-block fps-tag-{day=11, month=4, year=2018}">
                                                            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                                                                <dt class="text-left">Completed Date:</dt>
                                                                <dd>11-4-2018</dd>
                                                            </dl>
                                                        </div>

                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>

                                            

                                            
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="js-list list-wrapper ">
                        <div class="list js-list-content">
                            <div class="list-header js-list-header u-clearfix is-menu-shown">
                                <div class="list-header-target js-editing-target"></div>
                                <h4 class="list-header-name-assist js-list-name-assist text-center" dir="auto">
                                    Approved
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="sortable-list ui-sortable" data-column-id="approved" data-column-value="approved Approved">

                                <div class="ui-sortable-handle">

                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="js-list list-wrapper ">
                        <div class="list js-list-content">
                            <div class="list-header js-list-header u-clearfix is-menu-shown">
                                <div class="list-header-target js-editing-target"></div>
                                <h4 class="list-header-name-assist js-list-name-assist text-center" dir="auto">
                                    Editing in Progress
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="sortable-list ui-sortable" data-column-id="editinprog" data-column-value="editinprog Editing in Progress">

                                <div class="ui-sortable-handle">

                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="js-list list-wrapper ">
                        <div class="list js-list-content">
                            <div class="list-header js-list-header u-clearfix is-menu-shown">
                                <div class="list-header-target js-editing-target"></div>
                                <h4 class="list-header-name-assist js-list-name-assist text-center" dir="auto">
                                    Awaiting Graphics
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="sortable-list ui-sortable" data-column-id="awaitgraph" data-column-value="awaitgraph Awaiting Graphics">

                                <div class="ui-sortable-handle">

                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="js-list list-wrapper ">
                        <div class="list js-list-content">
                            <div class="list-header js-list-header u-clearfix is-menu-shown">
                                <div class="list-header-target js-editing-target"></div>
                                <h4 class="list-header-name-assist js-list-name-assist text-center" dir="auto">
                                    Ready for Dubbing
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="sortable-list ui-sortable" data-column-id="readydubbing" data-column-value="readydubbing Ready for Dubbing">

                                <div class="ui-sortable-handle">

                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="js-list list-wrapper ">
                        <div class="list js-list-content">
                            <div class="list-header js-list-header u-clearfix is-menu-shown">
                                <div class="list-header-target js-editing-target"></div>
                                <h4 class="list-header-name-assist js-list-name-assist text-center" dir="auto">
                                    Ready for Grading
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="sortable-list ui-sortable" data-column-id="readygrading" data-column-value="readygrading Ready for Grading">

                                <div class="ui-sortable-handle">

                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="js-list list-wrapper ">
                        <div class="list js-list-content">
                            <div class="list-header js-list-header u-clearfix is-menu-shown">
                                <div class="list-header-target js-editing-target"></div>
                                <h4 class="list-header-name-assist js-list-name-assist text-center" dir="auto">
                                    Completed
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="sortable-list ui-sortable" data-column-id="completed" data-column-value="completed Completed">

                                <div class="ui-sortable-handle">

                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="js-list list-wrapper ">
                        <div class="list js-list-content">
                            <div class="list-header js-list-header u-clearfix is-menu-shown">
                                <div class="list-header-target js-editing-target"></div>
                                <h4 class="list-header-name-assist js-list-name-assist text-center" dir="auto">
                                    Not Approved -Do Not Distribute
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="sortable-list ui-sortable" data-column-id="notapproved" data-column-value="notapproved Not Approved -Do Not Distribute">

                                <div class="ui-sortable-handle">

                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="spacer-sml"></div>

        </form>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I get the error scale doesn't exist.  If I make it a string it still doesn't work, you still have to scroll.  I want to be able to zoom out enough that the scroll bar disappears.

Comment: that scrollbar is probably because of some faulty css html design.Will look into it and let you know

Comment: Thanks.  I am only looking to zoom out of the div board-canvas

Comment: I made a small change. Please check if it works for you

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't show up the rest of the content in the div board-canvas.

Comment: What content is not visible ? Can you please tell. Thanks

Comment: The zoom zooms out just the currently displayed content.  The Columns Completed and Not approved which you currently have to scroll across to see don't become visible as you zoom out.